# Anything like SiSoftware Sandra?

Tags: software-recommendation, hardware

SiSoftware Sandra is a hardware diagnostic tool for windows: http://www.sisoftware.net/
the time update my little note book has come, and i encountered the problem of not knowing 
what is the model of my processor(the notebook come in two flavours, its asus eee pc 1005ha btw and yes, i did try to google it).
and its very critical for me since im upgrading the ram.

edit:
sorry for the misunderstanding, i need to find out my processor model right now but i want to find similar software for future use that is more than just finding what is my processor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This question was originally another question, but it was edited or changed in at least 80% of the original question. 
However, this answer can yet be helpful for you.*

You may wish to give a try to HardInfo or Phoronics which doesn't indeed do as many things as Sandra does, but it shouldn't as we are talking about Linux Systems.

Take a look at:

## Hardinfo at http://hardinfo.berlios.de/HomePage

From the site: *System Profiler and Benchmark
HardInfo can gather information about your system's hardware and operating system, perform benchmarks, and generate printable reports either in HTML or in plain text formats.*

I prefer to use Hardinfo, here is my screenshot of a benchmark in action in my system:

[image]

## Phoronics at http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/

From the site: *The Phoronix Test Suite is the most comprehensive testing and benchmarking platform available that provides an extensible framework for which new tests can be easily added. The software is designed to effectively carry out both qualitative and quantitative benchmarks in a clean, reproducible, and easy-to-use manner.*

Comment: Both are in the default repositories, by the way

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know your cpu, and don't seem to need all the benchmarking SiSoft Sandra offers, you can try `sudo hwinfo --cpu`. Might be what you need (first of all do `sudo apt-get install hwinfo` if you don't have this packet installed already).

Also, Sysinfo will give you quite an ammount of information about your System (without benchmarking features, tho).

Answer (score 2):

...lshw...

See http://embraceubuntu.com/2007/02/18/find-hardware-specs-details-on-your-computer/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, lshw, but as sudo, and maybe with html-format to view it in the browser?

```
sudo lshw -html > lshw.html
```

It's more verbose with sudo, and maybe you can put it somewhere in the net, where you may access it in case of a damage.