# Are there any hardware diagnostic tools?

Tags: software-recommendation, hardware, tools

I would like to perform a hardware check on my two desktops.
Are there any general-purpose hardware check tools for Ubuntu that will check:

- the main board
- IDE devices (hard disks and CD players)

One of my desktops is about three years old and the other one is 10 years old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you ask is not specific for Linux/Ubuntu and can be achieved with 3rd party software. For instance: [Ultimate boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) might be helpful.

[image]

See the link for a long long list of tools that it has. Amongst it are BIOS, CPU, Hard Disk Information & Management, Hard Disk Diagnosis and memory tools. It also includes gparted and a resize program.

Answer (score 9):

I like [System Profiler and Benchmark](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/hardinfo) found in the software center. Project homepage is [here](http://hardinfo.berlios.de/HomePage).

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Try [Linux-Hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/)'s hw-probe tool: https://github.com/linuxhw/hw-probe

The tool collects outputs of popular Linux diagnostics tool (smartctl, hdparm for IDE, dmidecode for board, etc.) and system logs (dmesg, etc.).

Use [this Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxhw/hw-probe/) in order to probe your hardware on Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution without the need to install anything on your host except Docker.

Probe example: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=0b29192f95

[image]

[image]
**...**

[image]

I'm the author of this project, so feel free to ask any questions in comments!

Answer (score 3):

### This answers is a copy of the one provided here: [Anything like SiSoftware Sandra?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28464/anything-like-sisoftware-sandra)

You may wish to give a try to HardInfo or Phoronics which doesn't indeed do as many things as Sandra does, but it shouldn't as we are talking about Linux Systems.

Take a look at:

## Hardinfo at http://hardinfo.berlios.de/HomePage

From the site: *System Profiler and Benchmark
HardInfo can gather information about your system's hardware and operating system, perform benchmarks, and generate printable reports either in HTML or in plain text formats.*

I prefer to use Hardinfo, here is my screenshot of a benchmark in action in my system:

[image]

## Phoronics at http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/

From the site: *The Phoronix Test Suite is the most comprehensive testing and benchmarking platform available that provides an extensible framework for which new tests can be easily added. The software is designed to effectively carry out both qualitative and quantitative benchmarks in a clean, reproducible, and easy-to-use manner.*