# ubuntu linux 13.04 kernel panic

Tags: 13.04, kernel

My problem is kernel panic when ubuntu linux 13.04 is loading. Can anybody understand log file content and explain me the reason of this problem? My other operation systems such as windows and linux mint can't boot too. I suppose that problem is hardware damage. But what kind of damage has happened? Thanks in advance.
log file:http://postimg.org/image/9ivbcfidt/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like memory related fault.  You may try running `memtest+` from your boot menu, or Ubuntu installation CD to make sure.

And there are some other tools available, that goes with more hardware tests and not only memory.  Some of them are presented as answer in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109935/are-there-any-hardware-diagnostic-tools) question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I made memtest. This tool checked my computer memory for 5 days. But it didn't find errors. I bought new computer memory. But error still exists.

Comment: @Belladonna try another tool.  http://www.ultimatebootcd.com is free and can make a hole lot of hardware tests.